# Зависла apt-get upgrade

Tags: linux, ubuntu

Прописал на сервере с Ubuntu 18.04 команды `apt-get update` и затем `apt-get upgrade`. На загрузке linux-firmware консоль зависла и ни на что не отзывалась. Закрыл её и в новой консоли хотел выполнить `apt-get autoclean`, на что сервер ответил:

> E: Could not get lock /var/lib/dpkg/lock-frontend - open (11: Resource temporarily unavailable)
>   E: Unable to acquire the dpkg frontend lock (/var/lib/dpkg/lock-frontend), is another process using it?

Что делать?

Comment: апгрейд еще работает. либо подождать либо рестартнуть сервер или убить команду. но лучше подождать)

Comment: @Taarim ждал-ждал и ничего не дождался. Убил процесс, потом сделал `dpkg --configure -a`. Вроде всё работает.

Comment: это нормальная тема. не раз уже влипало. Кстати замечал только на убунте и дебиане такие приколы.

Comment: @Taarim не удивительно, учитывая, что apt только на дебияне и бубунте:)